# gitk equivalent in atlassian stash

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I use atlassian's Stash for source control and want to give the release manager a nice graphic view over the source.

This is possible using git bash, but I don't want him to perform a pull every time, but to look on Stash and see the brances tree (gitk in git bash) graph over there.

So, my question is what is the gitk equivalent in Stash?

Thanks!

(For future comments: I already googled it and search in other questions but didn't find the answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're committed to using Stash, I think you're out of luck. There is currently an [open ticket](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/STASH-2534) to add this feature to Stash. You can vote for that ticket to be resolved if this is an important feature for you, but it has already been open for over a year.

As you mentioned, this can be done locally. Why don't you want the release manager pulling (or fetching) the repository? Atlassian's [graphical client SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) can make the process quite painless.

Comment: thank you very much, I will checkout the local graphical tool.
It's too bad that this ticket is open for so long, I'll upvote it.